# What is the difference between the spark physical plan and what is displayed as a DAG in the spark web UI sql tab?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I used to think that these two, the spark physical plan and what is displayed as a DAG in the spark web UI SQL tab, should be exactly the same except that the DAG in the SQL tab would be populated with statistics from actual runtime. Hence, the contents of the SQL tab in the web UI are even visible only once an action is called (because it wants these runtime statistics)

However, this is not the case:

end to end runnable example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=  pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1_000).reshape(-1,10))
df1.index = np.random.choice(range(10),size=100)
df1.to_csv("./df1.csv",index_label = "index")
############################################################################

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, StructField

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold","-1").\
config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled","false").getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([StructField('index', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('0', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('1', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('2', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('3', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('4', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('5', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('6', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('7', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('8', StringType(), True), 
                     StructField('9', StringType(), True)])

df1 = spark.read.csv("./df1.csv", header=True, schema = schema)

df2 = df1.select("index","0","1")
df3 = df1.select("index","2","3")

df4 = df1.join(df2,on='index').join(df3,on="index")

df4.explain(mode="formatted")
df4.count()
```

Output (Physical plan):

```
== Physical Plan ==
* Project (16)
+- * SortMergeJoin Inner (15)
   :- * Project (10)
   :  +- * SortMergeJoin Inner (9)
   :     :- * Sort (4)
   :     :  +- Exchange (3)
   :     :     +- * Filter (2)
   :     :        +- Scan csv  (1)
   :     +- * Sort (8)
   :        +- Exchange (7)
   :           +- * Filter (6)
   :              +- Scan csv  (5)
   +- * Sort (14)
      +- Exchange (13)
         +- * Filter (12)
            +- Scan csv  (11)
```

**There are 3 separate scans of the data shown in the physical plan above.**

However, **the SQL** tab in the web UI looks like the following and, **has just one scan of the data**:

[image]

What is the difference between the spark physical plan and what is displayed as a DAG in the spark web UI SQL tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `.explain` is one of the several candidate physical plans that spark generates.

The plan showcased in the SQL tab of the web UI is the final (most optimal given the system settings) plan that gets executed. It contains optimizations on top of the physical plan such as reusing exchanges